# jQuery Form Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an simple form that's not meant to functional, it's just for a prototype. Here's the HTML:

```
<form class="signup">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="row">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password">
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

I need to have it so if a user was to input some data (dummy data) into the username and password and click submit, it'll show a JavaScript alert saying "Logged in" and if one of the inputs doesn't contain any data, I'd like it to show a JavaScript alert saying "Error".

I want to use jQuery and this is what I have so far:

```
$('.signup').submit(function () {
  if($(this).valid()) {
    alert('Logged in');
  }else {
    alert('Error!');
  }
});
```

Any reason why that's not working?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're attempting to use the [jQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). Make sure you're including that on your page as well, as `valid()` is not a function that is included with jQuery.

Comment: I've included jQuery, jquery.form.js and jquery.mockjax.js and it's still not working.

Comment: Do any of those have a `valid()` method?

Comment: Instead of using valid, can I show an alert if the inputs have content in them?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for your latest question:

```
$('.signup').submit(function () {
    if( $('input[type="text"]').val()!='' && $('input[type="password"]').val()!='' ) {
        alert('Logged in');
    }
    else {
        alert('Error!');
    }
});
```

Comment: It works although if I were to change `alert('Error!');` to add a class to an element (to show the error), it gets removed after less than a second.

Comment: Aha, I think I found it. I forgot to add `return flase;`.